# Script to get the Email Alerts for RDP Session

Tags: security

Is there any script to get the Email Alerts when someone logs into the server so that I can increase server security by getting the Email alerts.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I am interested in getting an answer to this.

Answer (score 2):

How do you think this is going to increase security?

If I've RDP'ed into the server and nicked a load of credit card data stored on it, you receiving an email hasn't prevented me from logging in. The damage has already been done, and no amount of securing the server after the matter is going to please anybody.

If you really want to secure RDP access to the server, you can restrict who is allowed to Remote Desktop into machines on a per machine basis. You can add Security Groups, as well as individual users if you want to run like that.

Comment: +1. Thanks, Ben. Sometimes I'm at a loss with some of the questions here.

Comment: Forensics is a key part of security. Being able to find out what happened, when and how is is very important for a number of reasons. Getting an email on a remote login is definitely better, than not getting one - e.g. you can go and "plug off" the server that was breached ... much better than giving an attacker the much valuable time to start digging into your data.