# How to execute a script whenever an RDP session is established

Tags: windows

I'd like the host that I connect to through RDP to execute a script when the connection is established.

Setting `Local Computer Policy -> User Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Scripts (Logon/Logoff) -> Logon` seems not to work for RDP

Basically, I'd like to achieve the same as in this unrelatedly answered [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/211063/script-to-get-the-email-alerts-for-rdp-session).

Comment: Maybe you can try this: https://superuser.com/q/1073760/378809

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks!